# Check table doesn't exist in dynamoose

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

When I try to get data from dynamoDb I am getting exception Resource Not Found exception. It is not going inside catch block as well so that I can catch the exception. Due to this I am getting runtime error. How to handle this error?

```
 this.getModel()
            .query(queryfilter)
            .attributes(attr)
            .exec();
    }
```

Comment: can you show us your code with the try/catch block, how you are trying to catch the exception?